# Comparing two JTextFields with an ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, compare

what I am trying to do is compare two inputs from TextFields within a JFrame using an ActionListener. If the two inputs are equal and the user hits the button, a MessageDialog will pop up and say "equal". If they are not equal, a MessageDialog will pop up and say "not equal". I have the frame and ActionListener running, I just do not know how to take the inputs from the TextFields and compare them.

For example, if the user enters something like this,
[Equal TextFields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pw2hB.png), this will pop up, [Equal Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyeS2.png)

Here is my Main Class:

```
public class LabFiveOne
{

public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("String Equality Program");

    JTextField tf1 = new JTextField(10);
    tf1.setActionCommand(tf1.toString());
    tfListener tfListen = new tfListener(tf1);
    JTextField tf2 = new JTextField(10);
    tf2.setActionCommand(tf2.toString());
    JButton chEq = new JButton("Check Equality");
    chEq.addActionListener(tfListen);

    JPanel nPanel = new JPanel();
    nPanel.add(tf1);
    nPanel.add(tf2);
    frame.add(nPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    JPanel sPanel = new JPanel();
    sPanel.add(chEq);
    frame.add(sPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    nPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    frame.pack();

    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

And here is my ActionListener Class:

```
class tfListener implements ActionListener
{
    private final JTextField tf3;

    public tfListener(JTextField nameTF)
    {
        tf3 = nameTF;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("abc"))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "equal");
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "not equal");
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: If textfield1.getText().equals(textfield2.getText()) ...?

Comment: If you are happy with this answer, please upvote and accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: ok than try to change the constructor in your ActionListener Class to

public tfListener(JTextField tf1, JTextField tf2){

```
{
```

Hi :) just don't overthink and you should be fine. The simple way would be to implement the ActionListener directly to your Main Class like this:

```
public class LabFiveOne
{

public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("String Equality Program");

    final JTextField tf1 = new JTextField(10);
    tf1.setActionCommand(tf1.toString());
    tfListener tfListen = new tfListener(tf1);
    final JTextField tf2 = new JTextField(10);
    tf2.setActionCommand(tf2.toString());
    JButton chEq = new JButton("Check Equality");  
    chEq.addActionListener(tfListen);


    JPanel nPanel = new JPanel();
    nPanel.add(tf1);
    nPanel.add(tf2);
    frame.add(nPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    JPanel sPanel = new JPanel();
    sPanel.add(chEq);
    frame.add(sPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    nPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    frame.pack();

    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

{

```
class tfListener implements ActionListener
{
private final String tf1text;
private final String tf2text;


public tfListener(JTextField tf1, JTextField tf2)
{
    tf1text = new String(tf1.getText());
    tf1text = new String(tf2.getText());

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(tf1text.equal(tf2text))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "equal");
    }
    else
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "not equal");
    }
}
```

}
}

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer but unfortunately, I cannot implement the ActionListener into my main class.

Comment: Thank you, I've made progress but when I try to add the line "tfListener tfListen = new tfListener(tf1);" to the code, it is saying that I need to add the constructor when I've already made it.

Comment: now you should use tfListener tfListen = new tfListener(tf1,tf2); because your constructor now expects two JTextFields ;)

Comment: Awesome, there are no errors now but no matter what I enter in the TextFields, I always get a "not equal" message. I believe it is because I haven't converted them to strings. No matter how I try to convert it to a string, it gives me an error. Can you suggest a way to convert them?

Comment: so I was able to do "if (tf.getText().equals(tf2.getText()))" but it is still giving me "equal" everytime.

Comment: @Brandon the problem is that your tfListen object is not going to be updated with new values of tf1text and tf2text. Make two setters for tf1text and tf2text inside the tfListener Class. After that add some ActionListeners in the Main Class to tf1 and tf2 (FocusListener) and when Focus is lost it should do: tfListen.setTF1text(tf1.getText()) and tfListen.setTF2text(tf2.getText())

Comment: Thank you for all your help! It is up and running now!

Comment: Perfect @Brandon ! Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

```
tf1.toString();
```

Shows you some information from the JTextField.
use another methods to get your input from the field. I mean it's the method:

```
tfi.getText();
```

Better look in a JTextField javadoc

Answer (score 0):

To be honest with you, I don't think you need two classes; one for implementing the GUI and one for handling the ActionListener when you can have everything in one class like the class below

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class LabFiveOne implements ActionListener
{

private JFrame frame;
private JPanel nPanel, sPanel;
private JTextField tf1, tf2;
private JButton chEq;

public static void main(String[] args)
{   
    new LabFiveOne();
}

public LabFiveOne(){
    frame = new JFrame("String Equality Program");

    tf1 = new JTextField(10);
    tf2 = new JTextField(10);
    chEq = new JButton("Check Equality");
    chEq.addActionListener(this);

    nPanel = new JPanel();
    nPanel.add(tf1);
    nPanel.add(tf2);
    frame.add(nPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    sPanel = new JPanel();
    sPanel.add(chEq);
    frame.add(sPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    nPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    frame.pack();

    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String action = e.getActionCommand();

    if(action.equals("Check Equality")){
        String number1 = tf1.getText();
        String number2 = tf2.getText();

        int num1 = Integer.valueOf(number1);
        int num2 = Integer.valueOf(number2);

        if(num1 == num2){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Equal");
        }
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not Equal");
        }
    }
}
}
```

I have everything declared globally so that the ActionPerformed method will have access the values in the Textfields.